# Average viewing angle of a convex body from a curve.

Tags: differential-geometry

This is an integral geometry question. Let $K$ be a convex body in the plane, and $\mathcal{C}$ a simple closed curve the interior of which contains $K$. From each point $P$ of $\mathcal{C}$ two tangent lines can be drawn to $K$ forming an angle $\theta(P)$ that is called the "viewing angle of $K$ from $P$". In the case of two concentric circles the average viewing angle of the inner disk from the outer circle is $2\pi$. Is this the case for more general bodies $K$ and surrounding curve $\mathcal{C}$?

Comment: This is completely useless, but I think the answer is *Yes*, and I think I learned this from an article of Serge Tabachnikov, which I cannot find now...

Comment: This, if true, would be a tool toward the proof of a long-standing conjecture.  If by some miracle you should track that article down, please be sure to let me know!  You can email me directly at jewetz@comcast.net.